# MySQL multiple AND condition from different table

Tags: mysql, sql

I have the following database structure:

product

```
+---------+-------+--------+
|  name   |  upc  |  model |
+---------+-------+--------+
| Value 1 | 1,234 | phone  |
| Value 2 | 2,345 | tablet |
+---------+-------+--------+
```

product_import

```
+-----------+---------------+----------+
| to_import | id_oc_prd_map | category |
+-----------+---------------+----------+
| 1         |       1,234   | apple    |
| 2         |       2,345   | banana   |
+-----------+---------------+----------+
```

I would like to get rows from product table with multiple conditions:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE upc IN (SELECT id_oc_prd_map FROM product_import) 
AND product.model = 'phone' 
AND product_import.category = 'apple'
```

- select items by common key (upc & id_od_prd_map)
- model = 'phone'
- category = 'apple'

In the example above I should get

```
+---------+-------+--------+
|  name   |  upc  |  model |
+---------+-------+--------+
| Value 1 | 1,234 | phone  |
```

as results, but I get error for second AND statement, because it is in another table.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just find the `upc` where category equals 'apple':

```
SELECT *
FROM product
WHERE upc IN (SELECT id_oc_prd_map FROM product_import WHERE import.category = 'apple') 
AND product.model = 'phone'
```

or use:

```
SELECT *
FROM product
INNER JOIN product_import ON product_import.category = 'apple'
                          AND product_import.id_oc_prd_map = product.upc
WHERE product.model = 'phone'
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use a simple [INNER]**JOIN** including **ON** clause to join tables, and **WHERE** clause to add extra criterias such as

```
SELECT p.*
  FROM product AS p
  JOIN product_import AS pi
    ON p.upc = pi.id_oc_prd_map
 WHERE p.model = 'phone' 
   AND pi.category = 'apple'
```

where no need to repeat whole table names but aliases

<kbd>[Demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=128742f2eb94558a38107b6f6b5bc87d)</kbd>